# How to get all VirtualFile of a project using intellij plugin sdk

Tags: intellij-plugin

How to get all VirtualFile of a project using intellij plugin sdk. Also are there any books or tutorial for advanced intellij plugin development.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Getting all VirtualFiles for a project is extremely unlikely to be the right way to accomplish your task.

Comment: I need to update a file in my project, for example test.java. I have to get this file and then update this file. So from virtualfile we can get Document and then the file can be updated. Basically scan the entire project and get a particular file and update the file.

Answer (score 3):

Your task does not require getting all `VirtualFile`s of a project. To get a `VirtualFile` for a specific file in your project, use `LocalFileSystem.getInstance().findFileByIoFile()`.

Comment: Thanks it helped... :)